# maintaining main thread frame rate with process intensive child threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco

I'm using POCO for threads.

I have the main thread that does all the opengl drawing, it has an update() and a draw() that are called each frame, the framerate is set to 1/60 seconds by sleeping for the remainder of that time after both funcitons have run.

this main thread has 2 child (POCO) threads for loading and playing sound files, sometimes the files need to be decoded. when the sound files are loaded in their thread, they go through beat detection in another child thread.

when the sound files need decoding, I'm getting terrible frame rates in the main thread, I want guaranteed 60 fps but it can go down to 2 when decoding, obviously the cpu is allowing these sound file threads way too much time for execution.

What I would like to do is specify that if each thread hasn't done their work 1/60 seconds from the time the main thread started it's update() function, then execution will stop until the next update() loop has finished in the main frame. I would also like to specify that the main thread is very important and it must have finished its update() and draw() functions before any other thread has a chance to run.

Comment: Did you try simply giving the main thread a higher priority?

Comment: http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Thread.html#17699

Comment: I'm on mac but I would like to remain portable to windows

Comment: I overlooked that you were using POCO. See the above link.

Comment: I'm using POCO for the child threads but I didn't create the main thread myself. I assume I could just set the POCO threads to the lowest priority, unless theres a way to specify the priority of the main thread.